# Restart networking in ubuntu karmic (9.10) using upstart

Tags: ubuntu, service, ubuntu-9.10, upstart

As far as I know karmic uses upstart to control some of the services.
Is there any way to restart the networking service without rebooting the system?

The problem is that when I try to do it in any way I know I fail.

`sudo service networking restart` reports:

> restart: Unknown instance:

`sudo initctl restart networking` reports:

> initctl: Unknown instance:

`sudo invoke-rc.d networking restart` reports:

> Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

All I need is just to launch a script which was recenltly added to `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want a different jobspec. Try one of these:

```
sudo initctl restart network-manager

sudo initctl restart network-interface INTERFACE=eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for the second recipe.
But alas it doesn't run any of the scripts from /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/